# How to merge two patches(git log) of different repository

Tags: git, git-log, git-am

I have a use case where I wanted to merge some sub directories of two repositories in a new repo.

For this, I have created patch for both the repositories for the directories I need using

```
git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- path/to/file_or_folder > patch1
git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- path/to/file_or_folder > patch2
```

Now, I wanted to merge both the patch in the new repository using git am, when I am doing it the commit history is coming repo by repo (which is expected). Is there a way I can get the commit history sorted by date, irrespective of where the commit came from?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce patches to be consumed by `git am`, you should use `git format-patch`, not `git log`.

The commit history is never sorted by date, but always like parent / child relationship. The dates are rather unimportant for order of commits.

What you probably should do is to use `format-patch` to produce one `am`-appliably patch file per commit, then order those commits by author date and use `git am` in that order on the patch files, then the commits are ordered like you want them to I think.

Comment: As you said: "order those commits by author date" . Is there a automated way to do that or I just have to do it manually  ?

Comment: You can write a script that does it for you or do it manually. Either way you should make sure that the order within each of the two sets of patches is maintained. The commits in one repository do not have to be ordered by author date e. g. if you used rebase and cherry-pick on those commits before.